# Azuresql-Invalid character value for cast specification

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

```
Im trying to import data from flat file(.dat) into azure sqldb for first time (new to azure) using below command.i'm getting error as shown below.
```

command used:
*bcp NAV_MO_MB in /Users/n1234/Documents/Tickets/Tickets/NEXT/SGC_test.dat" -f -S
stage-nonprod-5f188055.database.windows.net -d amlstage -U aml_user -P -q -t"|" -c -e /Users/n1234/Documents/Tickets/Tickets/NEXT/err_log.txt -F2.*

````
SQLState = 22005, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Invalid character value for cast specification
SQLState = 22001, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]String data, right truncation```

data sample : SGC |          ?|     4762|    7001297|  20/03/10|15:38:00  |          91|              1|         331|                   0|           1|                            |     -99.71|           100|         37|           353.71|OLGA                               |SILVA                              |           |613 CAMINO                                                                      |WALNUT                        |CA           |0          |9095697291        |CA            |US            |  53/06/10|CAN4431594                              |          1|   0                                    |                0
    table created using bewlo query in sqldb**

    ```SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[NAV_MO_MB](
    [SOURCE] [varchar](6) NOT NULL,
            [VENDOR] [nvarchar](35) NULL,
            [store] [INT] NOT NULL,
                [visit] [int] NOT NULL,
                [tran_date] [date],
                [tran_time] [time](7) null,
                [reg_nbr] [smallint] null,
                [trans_nbr] [int] null,
                [op_nbr] [int] null,
                [vo_ind] [tinyint] null,
                [seq_nbr] [int] null,
                [acc_nbr] [nvarchar](40) null, 
               [amt] [money] null,
                [code] [smallint] null,
                [tender] [tinyint] null,
                [vamt] [money] null,
                [first_name] [nvarchar](35) null,
                [last_name]     [nvarchar](35) null,
                [middle_init] [nchar](1) null,
                [address_line1] [nchar](30) null,
                [city_name] [nvarchar](30) null,
                [state_code] [nchar](2)  null,
                [postal_code] [nchar](10)  null,
             [phone_nbr] [nchar](18) null,
                [photo_id] [nchar](2) null,
                [photo_id_cnt]   [nchar](2) null,
                [birth_date] [date] null,
                [id1_nbr] [nvarchar](40) null,
                [id1_type_code] [smallint] null,
             [national_id] [nvarchar](32) null,
                [govt_id_code]   [smallint] null
    ) ON [PRIMARY]```
    
    

    **Please help me to understood the error and the resolution?.**
````

Answer (score 0):

You have some trailing invalid characters.

The last line : [PRIMARY]''''

Remove the '''' at the end.

Sometimes this happens when you copy and paste code.